# Pass root domain to JS Script

Tags: javascript

I want to replace facebook.com with my root domain

```
<script>
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['facebook.com']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

How can I get the root domain where this code is installed and replace facebook for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window.location` object has many properties including `hostname`

If I understand you correctly you want:

```
ga('linker:autoLink', [window.location.hostname]);
```

On this page for example it would return `"stackoverflow.com"`

Comment: Yeah that's it. I didn't know about hostname, sweet.

Comment: worth taking a second to log the location object to console and see all the properties it does contain for future reference